# Получить активный класс слайдера js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть слайдер

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.right').click(function() {
    let arr = [];
    $('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
      curSlide = $('.active');
      arr.push(curSlide[0].classList[1]);
    });
    console.log(arr);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item image11 active">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/9-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image10">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/7-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image9">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/8-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image8">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/3-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image7">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/1-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image6">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/2-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

получаю [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как его обработать не могу понять, подскажите как мне получить image10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно, я не понял, что именно вам было нужно, поэтому сделал наугад.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    let res = e.relatedTarget.classList[1];
    console.log(res);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item image11 active">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/9-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image10">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/7-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image9">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/8-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image8">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/3-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image7">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/1-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item image6">
      <img src="https://perestroyka.market/image/cache/catalog/_1_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F/2-700x700.jpg">
      <div class="title-slider">test2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо что отписались, я наверно не корректно объяснил,   `$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {` это bootsrap slider, и он отдает переключенный активный класс, ваш код отдает активный класс передушивший, а мне нужен класс активный который уже перелистнулась картинка

Comment: @Sender1050 А массив вы зачем тогда прописали? Я думал, вы там хотите сохранять все пролистанные слайды.

Comment: мне нужно получить только один активный класс, я его могу получить внутри это конструкции   `$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {` но проблема в том что когда перелистываешь несколько слайдов то он мне отдает несколько ответов и получается что я несколько запросов делаю на сервер, и чем больше я перелистываю тем больше одинаковых ответов мне дает

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hU1mujE.png это я два раза прокрутил слайд

Comment: это уже от безысходности пробую разные варианты как передать этот класс за приделы этой конструкции

Comment: @Sender1050 Я поправил свой код, теперь он выводит нужный вам активный класс слайдера. Ну, если я правильно вас понял.

Comment: да спасибо он отдает то что нужно, но проблема заключается в том что он при трех перелистованей слайдера отдает по несколько одинаковых ответов, вот приведу пример со скринами https://i.imgur.com/nj9aljo.png это я один раз нажал на стрелочку все хорошо отдал один ответ, https://i.imgur.com/oZj2slI.png это еще раз нажимаю на стрелочку и он мне отдает уже 2 image9, и чем больше я пркручиваю слайд тем больше он мне отдает повторок, как сделать что бы ответ был один не знаю.

Comment: @Sender1050 Я вам выше подправил свой же код, он выводит по одному элементу в консоль. Если уже у вас на сайте код начинает дублировать вывод в консоль, нужно видеть, что именно вы делаете с кодом. Может, вы его дублируете или какая-то функция его запускает несколько раз.

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь, ваш код работает так как нужно, буду у себя смотреть что его заставляет делать дубли

Comment: @Sender1050 Всегда пожалуйста. Вопрос закрыть не забудьте.